# Will my c++ program connect to local MySQL db from computers world-wide(outside of my LAN)?

Tags: c++, mysql, networking, network-programming

Can you tell me if i am correctly configured for any computer world-wide to run my program and successfully connect to my local MySQL database(running on port 3306)?

I have a C++ with MySQL connector program that connects to my WAN IP address on port 3306 like so:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://108.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306", "root", "pass");
```

I have set up port forwarding for port 3306->3306 to the computer on my LAN thats running my mysql server on port 3306.

This connects fine to my database when i run it on computer within my LAN, but will this work for world-wide computers?

Also, if i choose to run a c++ server instead on port 3306, will clients outside my LAN be able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

This certainly looks correct, but there are a couple of things to think about.

- First, why are you hard coding your IP address instead of using a
  hostname? What if your hosting provider changes?
- Are you comfortable handing out these specific login parameters to your database?  What if you want to
  change them?
- What do you mean by world wide computers?  Anything on the Internet, or do you really mean anything in world?

What are you really trying to do?

Comment: By world-wide i just mean any computer outside my LAN. I'm trying to create game server.

Comment: @shawna In that case you should most likely expose only your own network protocol to the world and keep MySQL private/local. If your game clients will connect directly to database that could lead to many problems and exploits.